# Why is this piece of code not working as I think?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, reference

here's a snippet:

```
Test & returnref(){
    Test *obj = new Test();
    cout << &obj << endl;
    return *obj;
}

int main(){
    Test &object = returnref();
    cout << &object;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and this code generates the following:

```
0016FBC8
004D4B98
```

why isn't it

```
0016FBC8
0016FBC8
```

?

I think, that if I return a reference to a dynamically created object (on a heap), it should be exactly the same object, so the addresses should equal.

Why am I wrong?

Comment: Because your function is printing the address of an automatic pointer variable; your `main()` is printing the allocated address held therein (and unrelated, also leaks memory).

Answer (score 7):

Here:

```
cout << &obj << endl;
```

you are printing the address of the pointer. What you really want is the address of the pointed object, which is `&*obj` or simply `obj`.

Comment: @02446 Also watch out for WhozCraig's comment -- your code leaks memory, you'll need to `delete &object;` when you're done with it.